# Use firebase with a third party JWT token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I want to use a third party JWT token (from my current auth system), generate a custom firebase token based on this JWT token and use this to access the firestore database.

My concept is the following:

1. App connects on startup to third party backend for authentication with email/password -> receive JWT Token
2. App calls own firebase function with this third party token
3. Firebase function validates token with public key of my third party backend
4. Return new custom firebase token created by admin-sdk
5. App connects to firebase with this new custom token

*I guess a better way would be to issue a (second) token from my third party backend (generated with the admin-sdk), but I have no real access to this third party backend.*

Is this a way to go for me? Or are there any other options based on my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase actually has a detailed explanation on [Authenticating with Firebase in JavaScript Using a Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) which is what you are planning to do. You verify that third party token and then [create a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) using `signInWithCustomToken()`. Then you can `signInWithCustomToken()` and use features like Firebase security rules with Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand this correctly my third party backend needs to issue a token with createCustomToken(), which means I have to modify this third party backend. Let's assume I can't change it, can I use my existing token and call an own firebase function, which will create a custom token?

Comment: @Lexycon no. You read user's UID from your existing auth system token, then pass that to `createCustomToken(<USER_ID>)` in the Cloud function where you decode your JWT. Then this custom token is used to sign in user with Firebase. Nothing needs to be changed on our custom server.

Comment: Thanks, I think i figured it out. In my app I send my existing auth system token to my new firebase cloud function (e.g. /login), the backend will verify that token (with pub key), decode the token and use its UID with createCustomToken(). The created token will be send back so the app can use it for further firebase calls.